# Find x in the following equation:

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find x in the following equation: $$\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}+1}+\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}} +\frac{x}{\sqrt{4}+\sqrt{3}}+...+\frac{x}{\sqrt{2025}+\sqrt{2024}}=4004$$

Comment: Hint: conjugates and telescoping sum.

Answer (score 4):

Note that
$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}}=\frac{x(\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n+1})}{(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1})(\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n+1})}=x(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}).$$
Thus the given sum will be
$$(\sqrt{2025}-1)x=4004.$$
This gives $x=91$.

Answer (score 0):

We get the following sum:

$$\sum\limits _{n=1}^{2024}\frac{x}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}=4004$$

If we look to sum we can say:

$$\sum\limits _{n=1}^{q}\frac{x}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}=\left(\sqrt{q+1}-1\right)x$$

So we get:

$$\sum\limits _{n=1}^{2024}\frac{x}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}=4004<=>$$
$$x\left(\sqrt{2024+1}-1\right)=4004<=>$$
$$x\left(\sqrt{2025}-1\right)=4004<=>$$
$$x\left(45-1\right)=4004<=>$$
$$x\left(44\right)=4004<=>$$
$$4x=4004<=>$$
$$x=\frac{4004}{44}<=>$$
$$x=91$$